# Javafx Mediaview settings according to scene property

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am trying to change media view height and width according to media player window.
So please tell me how can I do by adding scene.setonzoom().

Comment: Explain `according to media player window`.

Comment: I just wanna know that how to add event handler in setOnZoom

Comment: From what I understand you want your `MediaView` height and width to change according to the height and width of stage. Do I understand the requirement correctly?

Comment: I wanna update media view height and width on zooming javafx window. Media view should be fit on window.

Comment: Zoom window? Or resize the window?

Comment: Full size window... On maximizing the window, view should be full size

Answer (score 2):

In order to re-size mediaview along with the scene, bind the `fitWidthProperty` and `fitHeightProperty` of the `MediaView` with the scene's `widthProperty` and `heightProperty` respectively.

```
mediaView.fitWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty());
mediaView.fitHeightProperty().bind(scene.heightProperty());
```